# What is effect of the migration scheme on a database?

Tags: python, sql, database, database-migration

I am supporting a software that uses SQLAlchemy database on Python.
I need to add the column to this database. As I understand, I need to run migration on it to do this.

I am new to working with databases, so not sure how it would affect the database.
Will the people who currently use this software also need to run migration on their own environments to keep their database structure up-to-date?

Is there a way to get the user's darabases updated automatically?

Thank you

Comment: *“Will the people who currently use this software also need to run migration on their own environments”* – yes, but they won’t also need to *create* one. You create the migration, then everybody runs it. *“Could you please also advise which migration tool is best to use in my situation?”* You should probably remove this from your question, as Stack Overflow doesn’t do recommendation questions. One for SQLAlchemy that exists is [Alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/), though.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get the user's darabases updated automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) an a number of projects to solve this database migration problem, and found it to be highly effective.

Comment: So, as I understand, this database would allow the changes in db to be made automatically for users?

Comment: Liquibase is not a database.
The short answer is 'yes'. It can be embedded in your application such that on startup it will check to see if any schema changes/data migrations need to be applied, applies them automatically, and then continues with your application startup. 

I'd encourage you to peruse the liquibase website via the link I provided.